# Cloudfront: Marked as insecure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using S3 bucket hosting and created a certificate via Certificate Manager. I also created a CloudFront Distribution and can reach my website via https://test.mydomain.com. Only Problem: Chrome says the connection would be insecure.

If I check the details in tab security I get:

- valid certificate *.mydomain.com
- secure connection tls 1.2 but:
- Active content with certificate errors

What does the last mean? Where do I get details what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you let us know the domain name to take a look?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145936/chrome-active-content-with-certificate-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by closing tab an reopen the site... reload was not successful.

Comment: can you mark this as the accepted answer? It was exactly what I needed to see.