# How to determine exactly why chrome flags site as not secure

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, https

I just moved several interrelated sites from a server that does not support TLS 1.2 to one that does to specifically stop chrome's `site is insecure` message. There a 4 separate websites one of which has 2 pages Demo.aspx and Rater.aspx. All sites use https:// and the server supports TLS 1.2 and has a valid certificate chain. All sites load without any security warning, including Demo.aspx, but Rater.aspx does not (it is the only one).

Rater.aspx is a older and somewhat large one page asp site, so I figured there must be a http:// reference somewhere, and I found a few which I converted to https://.

I have gone over the site many time, and there is nothing I can see that should be causing the insecure flag.

Your Connection to this site is not secure.
Certificate (valid)
Cookies (1 in use)

Is there a tool that will tell me what chrome is picking up on so I can fix it?

If it would be helpful I can provide a link to the page, just did not want to do it here.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try looking in the Security tab of your browser's developer tools? What did it tell you?

Comment: @mason You have recently allowed content loaded with certificate errors (such as scripts or iframes) to run on this site. -- so even though I corrected the issues I am being penalized?

Comment: Interesting....I didn't know it would do that. If that's the case, you might want to take it up with Google. You might also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145936/chrome-active-content-with-certificate-errors).

Comment: @mason I saw that question after your initial response, clearing did not resolve it and I keep getting a NID cookie (google preferences) linked to a less secure domain I reference so that's probably what's causing it. The other sites also reference the same domain but don't get the NID cookie so they don't get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

As @mason pointed out Chrome's `Security` Tab in developer tools provides information on what is causing the `Not Secure` message and ultimately led to the discovery of an unused iframe pointing to a less secure domain.

I found the offending domain name on the `Application` tab under Local and Session storage (no actual data was being stored). A project search for that name found the iframe.

Of note is that the insecure server was https:// and has a valid SSL certificate but it does not support TLS 1.2.